# Is it possible to modify CRM 2011 tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, crm

Is it possible to modify CRM 2011 tooltips?  After fooling around with it for hours, it seems to be impossible.

The two different things I tried were:

- Browsing through the customizations XML looking for something tooltip-like to modify.
- Using Javascript to modify different "title" attributes I found in the HTML.

Everything I tried in Javascript went something like:

```
var StuffControl = document.getElementById("internal_field_name");
StuffControl.title = "whatever I want my tooltip to say";
```

When I tried running the above Javascript code on a lookup field specifically, it was able to execute and modify the lookup "title" attributes.  Infact, I was able to find two different "title" attributes embedded within one lookup field, and I successfully changed both of them.  However, changing either of the "title" attributes I found embedded within that lookup never resulted in actually modifying the tooltip.  The tooltip always stays set to its existing value.

I assumed the "title" attribute was the one I was looking to change, since that is the generic HTML tooltip attribute.  I also tried changing other attributes, but came up with the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modify a field label tooltip (which I believe all field types have), use the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("field_name_c").setAttribute("title", "tooltip text");
```

To modify a lookup button tooltip (lookup fields have two tooltips, one for the label and one for the button, aka the magnifying glass), use the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("field_name").setAttribute("title", "tooltip text");
```

The "_c" appended to the end of the internal name of the field stands for "caption", and is therefore associated with the label HTML element of that field.  In the case of lookup fields specifically which have the second additional tooltip, the exact internal name of the field matches the id of the lookup button HTML element.

Comment: just a note to remind future viewers that this approach is not a "supported customization" per the CRM SDK.  MS does not support any customizations that manipulate the CRM forms using the DOM directly.  As far as I know, though, there is no supported way to change the tooltip.